# axios how get status error without response

Tags: axios, try-catch

How can i get information about the error when there is no responce in the error? Through postman I see code 404, through catch I see code 0 in the request. How can I get 404 code?

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios('https://ms.com/s');
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.response);
    console.log(e.request);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.3/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = await axiosbase.get('https://ms.com/s')
    .then(response => {     
        return response;
     }).catch(response => {  
        return response;
     });

if(response.status === 200){
// do something here.
}
```